# How can I serialize a Linq query to database?

Tags: c#, linq

I need the ability to be able to store a Linq query as a string in the database and then load it and run it at a later date.

I am having extreme difficulty wrapping my head around how to do this.

I found this library that says it can do it: https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq

But the blog that held the documentation is down and I can't figure it out from the examples, too much is going on.

Can anyone show me or link me to a simple example of a linq statement being serialized and then deserialized and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best option performance wise (I'm not sure about it being good or bad), but this is an option to achieve the functionality you want.

The **IQueryable ToString()** Method allows you to programmatically retrieve the SQL that the IQueryable object will generate and run as the database query.

Then you can use that SQL string in **Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries**.

the examples below will use the out of the box Microsoft ASP.NET Identity DbContext.

IQueryable ToString() examples:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
IQueryable query = db.Users.Where(w => w.Email != null);
string generatedSql = query.ToString();
```

The string `generatedSql` will contain this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
[Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
[Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
[Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
[Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
[Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
[Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
[Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
[Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Email] IS NOT NULL
```

Here is an example using the Include() Method on the IQueryable object to show what kind of SQL this will generate:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

IQueryable query = db.Users
    .Include(i => i.Claims)
    .Include(i => i.Roles)
    .Where(w => w.Email != null);

string generatedSql = query.ToString();
```

After adding the Include methods the string `generatedSql` will contain this:

```
SELECT 
[UnionAll1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[Email] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll1].[PasswordHash] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll1].[SecurityStamp] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll1].[PhoneNumber] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll1].[AccessFailedCount1] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll1].[UserName] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll1].[Id1] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll1].[UserId] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll1].[ClaimType] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll1].[ClaimValue] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C21]
FROM  (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount1], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent2].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
    [Extent2].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4]
    FROM  [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Email] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    2 AS [C1], 
    [Extent3].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent3].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent3].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent3].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent3].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent3].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent3].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent3].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent3].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent3].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent3].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount1], 
    [Extent3].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
    [Extent4].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent4].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
    [Extent4].[UserId] AS [UserId1]
    FROM  [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent3]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent4].[UserId]
    WHERE [Extent3].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AS [UnionAll1]
ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[Id] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC
```

---

Then you can store those SQL queries however you like, and when you are ready to run them you can use **Entity Framework Raw SQL queries**.

Like this:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var users = db.Users.SqlQuery("Your SQL here");


//or this if you need your DbSet to be dynamic
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var users = db.Set<User>.SqlQuery("Your SQL here");


//or this for commands
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Your SQL command string here");
```

Comment: This seems like an ideal approach for me.  Thank you